# Preview in Chrome Dev Tools network panel is URL encoded

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'am trying debug with dd() in laravel application, but in preview in network of my http request I'm getting this output:

```
%3Cscript%3E%20Sfdump%20%3D%20window.Sfdump%20%7C%7C%20(function%20(doc)%20%7B%20doc.documentElement.classList.add('sf-js-enabled')%3B%20var%20rxEsc%20%3D%20%2F(%5B.*%2B%3F%5E%24%7B%7D()%7C%5C%5B%5C%5D%5C%2F%5C%5C%5D)%2Fg%2C%20idRx%20%3D%20%2F%5Cbsf-dump-%5Cd%2B-ref%5B012%5D%5Cw%2B%5Cb%2F%2C%20keyHint%20%3D%200%20%3C%3D%20navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC')%20%3F%20'Cmd'%20%3A%20'Ctrl'%2C%20addEventListener%20%3D%20function%20(e%2C%20n%2C%20cb)%20%7B%20e.addEventListener(n%2C%20cb%2C%20false)%3B%20%7D%3B%20if%20(!doc.addEventListener)%20%7B%20addEventListener%20%3D%20function%20(element%2C%20eventName%2C%20callback)%20%7B%20element.attachEvent('on'%20%2B%20eventName%2C%20function%20(e)%20%7B%20e.preventDefault%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7Be.returnValue%20%3D%20false%3B%7D%3B%20e.target%20%3D%20e.srcElement%3B%20callback(e)%3B%20%7D)%3B%20%7D%3B%20%7D%20function%20toggle(a%2C%20recursive)%20%7B%20var%20s%20%3D%20a.nextSibling%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%2C%20oldClass%20%3D%20s.className%2C%20arrow%2C%20newClass%3B%20if%20(%2F%5Cbsf-dump-...
```

Instead of the expected output:

````
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { doc.documentElement.classList.add('sf-js-enabled'); var rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\\[\\]\\/\\\\])/g, idRx = /\\bsf-dump-\\d+-ref[012]\\w+\\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if (/\\bsf-dump-...```
````

It worked prior to a Chrome update; is this a browser bug?

Comment: check in preview , here you can see dd data

Comment: in previw i see that first script which I did share in question, I posted just part of it, it's too long. In previw it shows that scripts instead of returned data :/

Comment: then do  it will show  you data list echo "<pre>"; print_r($all_ids); die();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New Chrome update recently changed the parsing/behavior of the preview tab, so it no longer parses the dd() output into human-readable text anymore, which sucks.

I found this post as I ran into this issue myself just now.

We'll probably a see a lot of posts on this soon, and then hopefully find a solution.

Also, checking the time you posted this, the update happened yesterday at around the time of posting this, so that's definitely why.

Comment: Oh, so this is happening because of chrome new update?..So definetly it sucks like you said.. :/ But thank you for info!

Comment: still no solution for this one? I have also the same experience

Comment: Can you add some details to this answer? Which update caused the problem? Are there release notes you can link to showing this change? Is there a bug report you can link to?

Comment: accessing chrome://settings/help and relaunching/restarting  chrome fixed this for me.

Comment: From version `Version 123.0.6312.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)` it is fixed. Thank you guys for the answer.