# strange behavior laravel 10 when use dd()

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio, vscode-extensions, laragon

i have code like this

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        return Fooservice::store($request);
    }
```

but when i saw in network my browser, it show diffrent. that show like this
"%3Cscript%3E%20Sfdump%20%3D%20window.Sfdump%20%7C%7C%20(function%20(doc)%20%7B%20doc.documentElement.classList.add('sf-js-enabled')%3B%20var%20rxEsc%20%3D%20%2F(%5B.*%2B%3F%5E%24%7B%7D()%7C%5C%5B%5C%5D%5C%2F%5C%5C%5D)%2Fg%2C%20idRx%20%3D%20%2F%5Cbsf-dump-%5Cd%2B-ref%5B012%5D%5Cw%2B%5Cb%2F%2C%20keyHint%20%3D%200%20%3C%3D%20navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC')%20%3F%20'Cmd'%20%3A%20'Ctrl'%2C%20addEventListener%20%3D%20function%20(e%2C%20n%2C%20cb)%20%7B%20e.addEventListener(n%2C%20cb%2C%20false)%3B%20%7D%3B%20if%20(!doc.addEventListener)%20%7B%20addEventListener%20%3D%20function%20(element%2C%20eventName%2C%20callback)%20%7B%20element.attachEvent('on'%20%2B%20eventName%2C%20function%20(e)%20%7B%20e.preventDefault%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7Be.returnValue%20%3D%20false%3B%7D%3B%20e.target%20%3D%20e.srcElement%3B%20callback(e)%3B%20%7D)%3B%20%7D%3B%20%7D%20function%20toggle(a%2C%20recursive)%20%7B%20var%20s%20%3D%20a.nextSibling%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%2C%20oldClass%20%3D%20s.className%2C%20arrow%2C%20newClass%3B%20if%20(%2F%5Cbsf-dump-compact%5Cb%2F.test(oldClass))%20%7B%20arrow%20%3D%20'%26%239660%3B'%3B%20newClass%20%3D%20'sf-dump-expanded'%3B%20%7D%20else%20if%20(%2F%5Cbsf-dump-expanded%5Cb%2F.test(oldClass))%20%7B%20arrow%20%3D%20'%26%239654%3B'%3B%20newClass%20%3D%20"

i alredy try reinstall my vsc, my laragon, my extension, switch another php and try adding path php to setting in vsc, still same result

Comment: I guess you use an Ajax request which expects JSON response, so the HTML view of your `dd()` function is interpreted as JSON, as text. Better to use Xdebug of course,  but you can use just `var_dump()` here to see something

Comment: thanks, it show like what i expected, awsome

Comment: Yeah, `dd()` renders interactive HTML and JS so you can inspect and interact with the output (expand/collapse sections, search, etc.). If you navigate to the Route associated with your `store()` method (assuming you can, easier said than done if it's expecting a `POST` instead of a `GET` request), you would see your output. Another way to see it is to return as `JSON`, like `return request()->json(['all' => $request->all()], 200);`, which you can then view as JSON in your browser, REST Client, etc.

Comment: [How make dd()¨works correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78192388/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

Check your Chrome settings (chrome://settings/help) for an update or relaunch required. Once I relaunched and completed the update, dd() started working properly again. I'm running Chrome Version 123.0.6312.87

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have stated, it is indeed caused by the latest update of Chrome browser. The user [SelfMade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8082165/selfmade) also explains it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78198579/20040064).
There is no solution for now, I would recommend using other browser or install some older version until they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the update from chrome://settings/help and try again. The problem will be fixed.

Comment: Wasn't this advice already given in an earlier answer?  Why repeat what has already been said?

Answer (score -1):

Because of chrome version. I changed to mozilla, now i can see the data with dd

Answer (score -1):

You are possibly using ajax requests, or a request that returns JSON format in your response. When you use dd() or ddd(), the page code is usually displayed in the response (as if it were rendering HTML).
You can handle this in two ways:

- Instead of using dd(), use var_dump();
- In an interpreter, you can copy the response and paste it into it. Some real-time interpreters do the instant loading for you.